# How to add an array as a node property in Neo4j and then compare it with some other nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these 3 nodes (User,Tweet,Token) like:

```
:User with this property {userID}
:Token with this property {word}
:Tweet with this properties {tweetID, userID, tweetTxt}
```

and the relations are as follow:

`(:Tweet)<-[:MADE]-(:User)
(:Token)<-[:CONTAINS {score}]-(:Tweet)`

Now consider the following csv file:

```
userToken.csv
_________________________________________
token,userID,score
that_danielle,15990804,0.111140564157
foodies,15990804,0.159946268074
soft-launched,15990804,0.132826927255
email,60730027,0.0561669544423
you,60730027,0.0835723672219
```

what I need to do is to add all the tokens from userToken.csv that have the same userID with :User node and add those tokens as an array property to :User node.

So what I expect is to have a new property on :User node called "tokenarray". Something like:

```
(u:User {userID: 15990804, tokenarray: ["that_danielle", "foodies", "soft-launched"]})
```

I tried the following but it only adds one token from the file to the :User node:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///.../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
Match (usr: User)
Where usr.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
set usr+= {tokenarray: [csvrow.token]}
```

How can I fix it? Also, after having what I explained, how can I go through one of the arrays and compare each of the elements by some other node property?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to in you last sentence. In any case, it should be posed as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should create the `tokenArray` (actually, a "collection" in neo4j terminology) for you:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///.../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH (usr: User)
WHERE usr.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
SET usr.tokenarray = COALESCE(usr.tokenarray, []) + csvrow.token;
```